# Parse text in the middle of a string - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have hundreds of rows in a string that look like this:

```
filler|filler|scrape this text|and this text|sometimes this to|filler|filler
```

Is it possible to select only the text after the 2nd | and before the last 2 |s?

Comment: What `SQL Server` version you are using ?

Comment: Recommend reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: What is your expected output and why? What is the meaning of -  last 2 |s?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: I would expect the output to be scrape this text|and this text|sometimes this to

Comment: I would suggest looking up a splitter that provides ordinal position, and omitting the "top" and "bottom" 2, and then rebuilding the string. But not storing your data in a delimited format is the *real* solution here; and why you're having the problem you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on 2016, string_split() would be an option, but there is no GTD of the order.  That said, consider a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SomeCol] varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
(1,'filler|filler|scrape this text|and this text|sometimes this to|filler|filler')

Select A.ID 
      ,B.Pos3
      ,B.Pos4 
      ,B.Pos5
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos3                Pos4            Pos5
1   scrape this text    and this text   sometimes this to
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON-based approach is also an option here. You need to transform the input text into a valid JSON array and get each array item with `JSON_VALUE()` by index (0-based).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   TextData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data (TextData)
VALUES (N'filler|filler|scrape this text|and this text|sometimes this to|filler|filler')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.TextData, N'|', N'","'), N'"]'), '$[2]') AS Text3,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.TextData, N'|', N'","'), N'"]'), '$[3]') AS Text4,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.TextData, N'|', N'","'), N'"]'), '$[4]') AS Text5
FROM Data d
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Text3               Text4           Text5
-----------------------------------------------------
scrape this text    and this text   sometimes this to
```